# PayPal integration. C# POST vs. WSDL

Tags: post, soap, paypal

I got the PayPal integration working well using plain old HTTP POST using C# & .NET 2/3.5.  I also get all transaction details in the response.

So, if I want to use WSDL (SOAP), will there be any advantage? (you can assume I know how to use web services)

Also, are there any examples on a complete C# project using this method?  I already looked at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42894/Introduction-to-PayPal-for-C-ASP-NET-developers
but that page tells very little about how to make a fully functional transaction using WSDL.

Any ideas?
Or "if it ain't broke, don't fix it"

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I really don't work from WSDL's very often because I'm primarily a PHP developer.  I have worked with them in Adobe Flex, though, and I gotta say I liked what I saw.

Basically, I was able to hook the WSDL up in Flex (which you can do in other IDE's as well) and it automatically gave me access to all of the API calls in the system.  I could see all of the possible requests (functions) available to the web service as well as how to build them without even referring to much documentation.

When building HTTP requests directly (NVP/XML/JSON/etc) you gotta refer to documentation quite a bit to see how to build the request, and there's typically more trial and error involved, too, until you get things working.  The WSDL helps you get around that, although, in reality you'll probably still be referring quite a bit to documentation.

The WSDL/SOAP tools I've used with PHP don't work nearly as nice as Flex or Visual Studio from what I've seen, so I typically stick to custom class libraries that build my requests for me. when I'm working in other platforms that utilize WSDL's a little nicer, though, I definitely prefer it.

Comment: Yes, the WSDL seems to work better. More important if the API changes a little, then I can easily find the new API calls.  I wish though there was some complete-ish project source that uses WSDL.